# Exception in the thread "main"

Tags: java, exception

Hello when I'm trying to run this code I'm getting following error
I understand this happens when there is no main function, however I do have a main fuction..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at FilterAs.main(FilterAs.java:21)
```

Here's my code

```
  import java.io.*;
public class FilterAs {
public static int numberOfFiles(File directory) {  
      if (directory.isFile())  
         return(1);  
      else {  
         File[] list = directory.listFiles();  

         int count = 0;  

         if (list != null)  
            for (File file : list)  
               count += (file.isFile()) ? 1 : numberOfFiles(file);  

         return(count);  
      }  
   }  

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      System.out.println(numberOfFiles(new File(args[0])));  
   }  

}
```

Comment: Well no it doesn't happen when you don't have a main function or not. Do you pass some argument to the command line when running your code?

Comment: Print out the value of args.length and you will see the problem. if args has no entries, then [0] index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to set arguments for your program?

You are accesing the arguments when calling the method (numberOfFiles).

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean?
I am pretty new and just thought this is how i help OP?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no command line arguments passed to the program, the following would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since the `args` array would be empty.

```
System.out.println(numberOfFiles(new File(args[0])));
```

You should check for the existence of such arguments before accessing the `args` array :

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    System.out.println(numberOfFiles(new File(args[0])));  
} else {
    System.out.println("Please supply a file name"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to:

```
args[0]
```

But `args` is empty.

You have called your program with something like:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

But you should have called it with:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar /a/path/to/some/directory
```

i.e. you need to pass an argument to your application.